# Como fazer unificar as janelas de exibição?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-requests

Boa tarde, estou utilizando 2 cameras em um projeto, mas quando executo o codigo ele abre em duas janelas diferentes, estou tentando fazer com que as duas imagems abram na mesma janela... Alguem poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

Este é meu codigo atual...

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime

print("Capturando o vídeo -- pressione <q> para encerrar...'")

direita = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
esquerda = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if (direita.isOpened() == False):
    print("Camera DIREITA não conectada!")
if (esquerda.isOpened() == False):
    print("Camera ESQUERDA não conectada!")   


data = datetime.now().strftime("%H.%M.%S_%Y.%m.%d")
fourcc1 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
fourcc2 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
file1 = ('C:/Users/Car/DIREITA/Direita ({}).avi'.format(data))
file2 = ('C:/Users/Car/ESQUERDA/Esquerda ({}).avi'.format(data))

out1 = cv2.VideoWriter(file1,fourcc1,6.0,(640,480))
out2 = cv2.VideoWriter(file2,fourcc2,6.0,(640,480))




while(True):
    ret, frame1 = direita.read()
    ret, frame2 = esquerda.read()
    cv2.imshow("DIREITA",frame1)
    cv2.imshow ("ESQUERDA",frame2)
    if ret==True:
        out1.write(frame1)
        out2.write(frame2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

direita.release()
esquerda.release()
out1.release()
out2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `hstack` do [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) para juntar as imagens. Pois imagens são matrizes.

Então em vez de:

```
cv2.imshow("DIREITA",frame1)
cv2.imshow ("ESQUERDA",frame2)
```

Dois frames são unidos como um frame único:

```
import numpy as np

# [...]
# Código

cv2.imshow ("ESQUERDA/DIREITA",np.hstack([frame1, frame2]))
```

> Obs.: As duas imagens precisam estar com a mesma resolução e números
>   de canais.
>
> Caso o espaço de cores não seja o mesmo, por exemplo um em
>   escala de cinza e outro BGR, converter para o mesmo espaço de cores
>   com `cv2.cvtColor(cinza, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`.
>
> A função `hstack` empilha as matrizes horizontalmente, então a altura
>   da imagem precisa ser igual. Caso queira um embaixo do outro, utilizar
>   o
>   [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).
>   Ou somente a função
>   [stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack)
>   para imagens muito diferentes.